# Java: Fail in synchronizing threads

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I have the following code:

```
for (int iThreadCounter = 1; iThreadCounter <= CONNECTIONS_NUM; iThreadCounter++){ 
  WorkThread wt = new WorkThread(iThreadCounter);
  new Thread(wt).start(); 
  m_arrWorkThreadsToCreate.add(wt); 
}
```

Those threads calls the following code:

```
int res = m_spLegJoin.call(m_workTread, m_workTread.getConfId());
```

And this is the call method inside LegJoinSp class:

```
public class LegJoinSp extends ConnEventSp {

    private static final int _LEG_JOIN_ACTION_CODE = 22;
    private static int m_nLegId = Integer.valueOf(IniUtils.getIniValue("General", "LEG_ID_START"));
    private final Lock m_lock = new ReentrantLock();

    public int call(WorkThread a_workThread, String a_sConfId) {

        synchronized (this) {

            //m_lock.lock();
            m_nLegId++;

            boolean bPass = false;

            Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.DEBUG, "LegJoinSp - call", "a_workThread = " + a_workThread.getThreadId() + " a_sConfId = " + a_sConfId);

            if (super.call(a_workThread, a_sConfId, _LEG_JOIN_ACTION_CODE, "" + m_nLegId) == 0) {

                bPass = true;

            } else {
                bPass = false;
            }

            //m_lock.unlock();

            if (bPass) {

                Log4jWrapper.writeLog(LogLevelEnum.DEBUG, "LegJoinSp - call", "a_workThread = " + a_workThread.getThreadId() + " a_sConfId = " + a_sConfId + " returned leg id " + m_nLegId);

                return m_nLegId;
            } else {

                return -1;
            }
        }

    }

    public Lock getLock() {
        return m_lock;
    }

}
```

I've got 2 threads calling this call() method.
m_nLegId is initiated with 100.
As you can see I have tried to lock the method with both

```
synchronized(this)
```

and

```
m_lock.lock() and m_lock.unlock()
```

The problem is that when I first get to **if (bPass)** inner code, it write 102 to my log as the m_nLegId value. However I expect it to be 101 because of the **m_nLegId++;** statement.
It seems that the second thread manage to get inside the code before the synchronize block ends for the first thread execution.

How can I fix that?

Thank you

Comment: You need to include more code, primarily how the `LegJoinSp` class is used. The easiest explanation for the behavior you see is that you are using two different objects, then synchronisation or locking a private lock won't do a thing.

Comment: @Kiskae I am not using both methods. I tried both of them  separately. One time synchronized and one time the lock object.

Comment: show the code that launch the threads following the rule MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: for (int iThreadCounter = 1; iThreadCounter <= CONNECTIONS_NUM; iThreadCounter++){

   WorkThread wt = new WorkThread(iThreadCounter);
   new Thread(wt).start();
   
   m_arrWorkThreadsToCreate.add(wt);
  }

Comment: I meant in your question not as comment

Comment: where do you create m_spLegJoin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me your bug is related to the fact that `m_nLegId` is a `static field` and you try to synchronize access on the current instance instead of the class such that you don't properly prevent concurrent modifications of your field.

I mean

```
synchronized (this) {
```

Should rather be

```
synchronized (LegJoinSp.class) {
```

**NB:** In case you only need a counter, consider using an `AtomicInteger` for your field instead of an int.

Answer (score 1):

The thing is you are creating a new object with every thread, but the way you applied the lock is applicable only to same object (as you applied the lock on the **this**).

 So if you want to apply the lock on the class level, then you can create a static object and apply the lock on that object which can serve the purpose you wanted to achieve (if I understood your problem correctly based on the comments)

Comment: Thank you zstring. Your'e answer is very similar to the one from Nicolas. So I voted for it but I cannot mark both as the solution.